# What file comparison tool can I use under OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, uti, macos

My favorite file comparison tool was Beyond Compare but since I recently switched to OS X, i'm no longer able to use it and I'm looking for an alternative, preferably a free one.

Update: I made the mistake not to specify that I am also looking for a tool that does directory comparison, not only files. Because this could make the already answers invalid I made another question for this [What directory comparison tools can I use on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10252/1916)

Comment: See my answer to your other question. Ditto anthonyg's recommendation.

Comment: [StackExchange Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Beyond Compare 4 now runs also on OSX. Visit http://www.scootersoftware.com/beta.php?zz=beta4_whatsnew

Comment: As a long time user of Beyond Compare (over 10 years), I could say that the only thing that I was missing from my old Windows period was BC. Now @orangebreeze will get a lots of votes as there is nothing so good as BC and I tried most tools.

Answer (score 59):

This is an aggregation of the answers posted on SO's deleted clone, [Graphical diff for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x). It includes links to each product, and the current price since last edit in USD.

Note that any links to SO will only be visible to users who can view deleted content, which requires either moderator privileges or 10k reputation on that site.

- Sourcegear's [DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), shareware
- Joachim Eibl's [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net), free
- Black Pixel's [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/), $69.99
- Bare Bones Software's [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com), free
- Araxis's [Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html), $129 + $29/year
- Deltopia's [DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/), $39.95/$75.95
- Kai Willadsen's [Meld](http://meldmerge.org), free
- Weipin Xia's [DiffFork](http://www.dotfork.com/difffork/), $26
- Biscade's [RoaringDiff](http://www.biscade.com/tools/diff/), free
- [tkdiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/), free

There were some other suggestions, which were not diff tools in their own right, which I will list below:

- It (Beyond Compare) runs well in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org), but I miss the shell integration. - [Danyal Aytekin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294855/danyal-aytekin), [May 11 '12, 13:01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x#comment13654610_3193658)
- Eclipse also has a fairly decent comparison mechanism. - [JeeBee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17832/jeebee), [Oct 9 '08, 12:45](https://stackoverflow.com/a/187084)
- P4Merge that comes with [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com) is pretty good and comes for free with perforce client. Both terminal and GUI version. - [amok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149157/amok), [Jul 7 '10, 23:19](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199634)
- I had to use [Vim](http://www.vim.org) because most of diffs mentioned here do not understand UTF-8. - user184880, [Oct 6 '09, 9:56](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1524646)

That about wraps up that thread's merge into this one, as [covered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174071).

Comment: For anyone using [MacPorts](http://macports.org/) `kdiff3`, `meld`, `tkdiff`, listed above, as well as [`xxdiff`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xxdiff/) are all available through `port install`.

Comment: I tried meld via Macports and a huge number of dependencies were required. I have since shifted to using TextWrangler's diff. This does directory comparisons and you can merge changes line by line. It doesn't do three way compare though.

Comment: FWIW meld is also available via brew. `brew install meld`.

Comment: P4Merge is free, very nice, can be used as both a diff and merge too, doesn't need to be downloaded with a perforce client anymore, and can even visually diff images! [Download here](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools)

Comment: Thank you so much..  **TextWrangler** is realy easy to use.

Answer (score 26):

FileMerge is bundled with XCode, but I prefer [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) which is not free.

Comment: To find FileMerge (assuming you have XCode) ...start up Xcode and choose 'Xcode' menu -> Open Developer Tool -> FileMerge. Or you can avoid starting up XCode by poking around in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app

Comment: When Harry Wood says "poking around" he means typing in the terminal:
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app

Comment: @Roberto or via Finder -> Go -> Go to folder... (Cmd+Shift+G)

Comment: Actually the way I tend to "poke around" is...  right click on 'Xcode.app' -> 'Show Package Contents'

Comment: @HarryWood @Roberto you can open filemerge from console without needing to poke around: `opendiff file1 file2`

Comment: Came here to find out how to open filemerge (i always forget!), and noticed i'd already left a comment explaining how in the past **\*high fives past self\***

Answer (score 13):

I use [Kaleidoscope](http://kaleidoscopeapp.com). Or just plain, old `diff` from the CLI

Answer (score 11):

It is not great, but the FileMerge bundled with the OS can be launched from the command line as `opendiff a.txt b.txt`.

Answer (score 7):

[DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/index.html) from Sourcegear is simple and free.

Comment: It looks to be much better than the FileMerge from XCode, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `diff` if you're using the command-line.

Answer (score 5):

[Changes.app](http://martiancraft.com/products/changes.html) has a great reputation and lots of features. [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) is great too, and has a beautifully designed UI.

It's also worth mentioning if you're doing programming that Xcode 4 has visual diff tools built in now too.

Comment: +1 for Changes.app Is the only one with a GUI which you can ignore both leading and trailing whitespaces..

Comment: Changes was acquired by BitBQ in October of 2012.  The latest link for changes is: http://bitbq.com/changes/

Answer (score 3):

There's also [DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/).

It's $40, and there's a trial available.

Answer (score 3):

Here are which I've found:

- FileMerge (opendiff)

  It's bundled with Xcode with Command Line Tools installed
- [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)
  It's bundled with Xcode with Command Line Tools installed
- [vimdiff](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/625/how-do-i-use-vim-as-a-diff-tool)

  It's free and open source. Install by: `brew install vim`.
- [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)

  Can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) via command: `brew install meld`, but probably it won't work.
- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)

  Can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) via command: `brew install kdiff3`
- [TkDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)

  Can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) via command: `brew install tkdiff`
- [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/)
- [VisualDiffer](http://visualdiffer.com/)

  Available at App Store
- [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/)

  Commercial with free trial.
- [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en)

  Commercial with free trial.
- [Changes](http://connectedflow.com/changes/)

  Commercial with free trial.

Check also [Comparison of file comparison tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) at Wikipedia
for the full list.

Answer (score 2):

There are a great many comparison tools available. Many do directories and files. Some even perform as merge tools (2 and 3 way). Of these some have already been mentioned in other answers and your choice will depend on what features you require, and how much you are prepared to pay for the tool. There is a good [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) with a comparison of many of the better known ones.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Folder Sync](http://www.destek.co.uk/foldersync/) It costs $8.99 on the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folder-sync/id433026186?mt=12&ls=1). It works really nicely.

Answer (score 1):

P4Merge is a free, very nice diff and merge tool. It can:

- Diff files
- Do 3 way merges
- Do Folder diffs
- Visually diff 2 image files!

[Download it here for Mac and Linux](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools)

**Some screenshots:**

[image]

**Visual diff of an image:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This tool https://filecomparisontool.com

1. Web based, so it is compatible
2. Mobile friendly
3. Save comparison up to 6 months
4. Share comparison via URL
5. It is free!

Answer (score 0):

vim also has built-in support for side-by-side diff -

```
vim -d file1 file2
```

Here is a page describing vim diff mode in detail -

http://www.carbonsilk.com/development/vim-diff/

Answer (score 0):

> GitX-dev is a fork (variant) of GitX, a long-defunct GUI for the git
>   version-control system. It has been maintained and enhanced with
>   productivity and friendliness oriented changes, with effort focused on
>   making a first-class, maintainable tool for today's active developers.

https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/

[image]