# Use Automator to compare directories

Tags: macos, automator, sort

I am wondering if there is a way to get Automator to compare two directories and sort the results in macOS Big Sur?

I have two large directories sitting up in a local network. I want to compare the contents of the two and find any folders/files that aren't in one or other and/or are different versions.

I had planned to just do it through command line using `diff -rq`. But, I was wondering if there is a way to run it through Automator and have it at least display the differences (but ideally sort for me!)?

Comment: RE: "(but ideally sort for me!)" --  Then you should edit your question and define what that statement means to you! How do you want the output sorted? That said, IMO, **Terminal** is the way to go, however you can use a **Run Shell Script** _action_ or even a **Run AppleScript** _action_ in an **Automator** _workflow_ to execute `diff -rq`. I'd use **Terminal** and redirect the _output_ to a _file_ and then use the various _command line utilities_ available to process the _output_, i.e. `awk`, `perl`, `grep`, `sed`, etc. It depends out how you want to _output_ sorted.

Comment: Have a look at the following answer for additional information with using `diff` and also read the _manual page_ of `diff`. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/what-directory-comparison-tools-can-i-use-on-os-x/228548#228548  -- You can read the _manual page_ for _`command`_ in **Terminal** by typing _`man command`_, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type _`command`_ and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: There are various apps that do this including FileMerge which is part of Xcode which is free.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm new to the terminal world, so these were helpful. I ended up where I wanted with the combo of diff, sort, and sed.