# diff lists nonexistent hidden files

Tags: macos

To verify that the dir I just copied to the external, exFat formatted hard drive has really the same contents,
I used [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228548/66939) solution. However `diff -rq` lists a lot of (if not all) files with a dot prepended only on the external drive.

Is this intended? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please add at least some of the relevant output.

Comment: ExFAT can't hold perms, ACLs or resource forks. That's what the dot files will be. Basically it's breaking the files and will reassemble on copying back to a Mac drive.

Comment: Okay thank you. What is "it"? Can I look this up somewhere?