# Why did Apple Decide not to install Command Line Tools as default?

Tags: xcode, command-line

Why did Apple Decide not to install Command Line Tools which now have to be installed through xcode?

Comment: Most of the binaries are already included in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/{Tools,usr/bin}`, and you can use commands like `xcodebuild -find SetFile` to find paths to them. Other App Store applications wouldn't be allowed to modify `/usr/bin/` either.

Comment: If there is a practical question you're looking to solve, let's edit that in so we can look at re opening this.

Answer (score 3):

**To answer your question**, not many (relative term here) OS X users will install or have any need for command line tools because it is part of a larger group of tools to download. A large majority of regular, everyday OS X users won't be using these programs. However, you do not have to install `Xcode` to install `command line tools` anymore.

Sign in to [Apple's Developer Downloads Page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and then search for `Command Line Tools`.

Download and install the latest as a `.dmg`.

[image]

**Related Question**: [How to download the Command Line Tools for Xcode without the Downloads for Developers webpage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/how-to-download-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode-without-the-downloads-for-devel)

### Alternative Way

As referenced from a [Stack OverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools/9964905#9964905), [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/ios_simulator__resigned/cltools_mountainliondp2_march12.dmg) is an unofficial link to the March 2012 Command Line Tools for Xcode.