# How do I install command line tools without installing Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I would like to install command line tools without installing Xcode as it is more than 4GB and I don't want to waste that much space since all I need are the command line tools. 
I have used `xcode-select --install` command but I still get an error message

```
active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`)
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install the Command Line Tools completely from the command line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107307/how-can-i-install-the-command-line-tools-completely-from-the-command-line)

Comment: No duplicate. The answer may match but the question is absolutely different.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), login with a valid Apple ID, search for "command line tools", download an appropriate version, open the dmg and finally install the tools.

Here is a direct link (which still requires an Apple ID!) to the latest non-beta version: [Command Line Tools OS X 10.11 for Xcode 7.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.1/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.1.dmg)