# How to install developer tools via ssh?

Tags: macos, xcode

How can I install Apple developer tools via ssh?

When I have a UI present running `xcode-select --install` in the terminal app or from remote opens a window with an install prompt.

Is there a way to do this via ssh in macos 11.6?

The ultimate goal is to automate this process and spend as little time as possible on that machine.
I need the python installation that comes with the developer tools to run ansible for further steps.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195963 for an answer.